# How to run Sencha Touch Application in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sencha-touch

i am  new to sencha touch & phone gap.i want to run simple hello word app in eclipse.but i dont know how to do it.if any one knows it than let me know fast
Thanks in advance 
Aamirkhan I.

**UPDATE:**

Well there is a plugin availble for eclipse in which we can easily create any sencha,jquery mobile,phonegap project's,just need to follow some steps to integrate that plugin..see 
[MY POST](http://techniques-android.blogspot.in/2012/06/making-phonegap-development-environment.html) 
for that plugin guide,i updated my answer just to help other's who don't know how to write sample application in phonegap eclipse.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this folder structure.

---your application name
-------src
--------------your activity class
-------gen
--------------generated files
-------android2.2
--------------generated files
-------Referenced Library
--------------Phone gap referenct which is placed in the libs folder
-------assets
--------------create folder www
---------------------place your html files & create sub folders for sencha files(
-------bin
--------------auto generated files
-------libs
--------------phonegap-1.3.0.jar
-------res
--------------some auto generated files
--------------create xml folder in that place phonegap.xml and plugins.xml files

-------Android Manifest
-------proguard.cfg
-------project.properties

Comment: This is clearly not the most efficient way to create a directory, there is a plugin in ecplipse for that. You can do so many mistake if you do it all by yourself

Comment: @TDeBailleul i used mds applaud plugin for eclipse but the app is showing empty white screen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323516/including-sencha-touch-2-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Start by doing the Getting Started tutorial of PhoneGap on whatever OS you want to work.

http://phonegap.com/start

You should get your Hello World pretty easily

And if you want to go further you can do that great Sencha Touch tutorial :

http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap/

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Apatna studio for the Sencha client development. It helps to build web applications quickly and easily and it is one of the Eclipse based powerful web development engine.

http://aptana.com/

Find Aptana Studio 3 Release Updates site: http://download.aptana.com/studio3-rcp/plugin/update/

Another alternative is Spket plugin for eclipse for Javascript. Spket Update site: http://www.spket.com/update/

Once your are done with the client development, you can follow the below link to build the different version of mobile application builds using phone-gap. [Visit here for Phonegap developers reference link](http://phonegap.com/start)

Comment: is there any other plugin to develop html css5 jscript apps for mobile platform in eclipse other than phonegap.

Comment: @prakash_d22. As per my understanding Sencha Touch 2 has the capability to do native packaging support for android and ios. But dont know how far they support hardware access.

Comment: but can u help me out with this doubt ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323516/including-sencha-touch-2-in-eclipse