# including sencha touch 2 in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, extjs, sencha-touch-2

i am using sencha touch 2 for first time .i have installed mds applaud plugin with sencha touch support for eclipse
i start  project by including sencha touch library as shown below.

[image: oops]

then i add sencha code as follows

[image: noops]

but when i run the programme in android emulator instead of printing hello world it shows blank white screen as below.

[image: loops]

can anyone help me how to run this application sucessfully ?

Comment: please check my [UPDATED POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339587/how-to-run-sencha-touch-application-in-eclipse) i had similar issue..you may be missing some thing try to follow steps i have given,if u have any qyery than post it here.

Comment: Please copy and paste your code here. The other screen shots are certainly useful so that we can see what you see.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to this, but I found that you can test the view in your browser by directing it to the folder that the app is in. For example, I just created an app called "TS2". The app is in the folder `C://xampp/htdocs/ts3` so I direct my browser to `http:// my ip here /ts3/assets/www/`. Of course I got the apache server running in XAMPP.

One more thing, I created the new app in the bash console and then imported it to Eclipse. In the screen you capped I selected "Create project from specific source directory" and then there is another option called something like import.

I hope this helps but, as I said, I'm still learning myself.